# Error con la biblioteca "BeautifulSoup". Este es el error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, script, windows10

Me encuentro haciendo un poco de code en python, versión 3.8.5. Tengo un error con la biblioteca "BeautifulSoup", ya probé desinstalándola y volviendo a instalarla, pero no consigo solución alguna. Este es el error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando abres una terminal (no dentro de VS) y desde ahí corres Python e importas bs4, ¿funciona? Si así sí funciona significa que tienes bs4 instalado en otra versión de python que no es la 3.8.5. Tienes que instalarlo dentro de la 3.8.5

Comment: por favor no pongas imágenes sino texto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)

Answer (score 0):

Te está diciendo que no tienes bs4 instalado, tienes que hacer:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

En el caso de que te encuentres en un entorno de Python distinto, tienes que activar ese entorno y ejecutar el comando de arriba.

**Nota:** es importante que al hacer la instalación lo hagas exactamente con el nombre que te he pasado, con las mayusculas incluidas.